# Ubuntu 20.04 HP mfp m127fw Printer Problem

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

After upgrading from the previous Ubuntu LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 the HP MFP m127fw printer no longer prints correctly. The printer didn't have any problems printing in Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 and the printer installation is unchanged.

It prints a few pages then pauses and then prints a few more pages and pauses. This continnues until the end or the print pdf.  The pauses are quite long, about five minutes. Some pages only have about 3 columns of print in the wrong format.

HPLIP is installed and has the drivers information files for the printer.

I'm using this printer on a network set up as a network printer with a static IP from the router via ethernet. Printer installation looks okay and the printer options can all be accessed...queues, print options etc.

The problem occurs when printing a PDF document either from a file directly or when printing PDF through the latest Google Chrome or latest  Firefox.

As a workaround, I take the same PDF and print it using Windows 10 or MacOS and it prints without problems.

Could the Ubuntu 20.04 driver be bad? Any ideas how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Investigate `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u cups`.